# display dialog after processing the link action

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have one primeface page certHollderList.xhtml:
In this page i have one expire Link. And on click  one action is fired and after processing the action, i want to open one dialog box in same page.

```
code 1:Expire Link::
    <h:commandLink id="expire" value="#{label.expire}" action="expire" immediate="true" oncomplete="dlg3.show()"
                                           update="dialogPanel">

 code 2 :: In the same page i added one outputpanel having a dialog box.

                                                                                                    <h:form> 
            <p:outputPanel id="dialogPanel" rendered="#     {certHolderSearchHandler.openDialog eq 'Success'}">
            <p:dialog header="Expire Holder Information" widgetVar="dlg3"
                showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="explode" appendToBody="true">
                <p:outputPanel id="dialogPanel1"
                    rendered="#{certHolderSearchHandler.openDialog eq 'Success'}">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Do you want to continue?" />
                        <p:spacer width="30" height="10" />
                        <h:outputText />
                        <p:spacer width="30" height="10" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <div align="left"><p:commandButton immediate="true"
                        value="Yes" action="continue" /> <p:spacer width="25" height="5" />
                    <p:commandButton value="No" action="cancel" /></div>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>      
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
```

And when i clicked the expire link,it doesn't open the dialog page. 
Please advise me....:(

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Primefaces model to actually update it:

```
 //JSF
 <h:form id="someForm">
   <p:commandLink
      id = "expire"
      value="#{label.expire}"
      actionListener="#{myBean.doSomething}"
      oncomplete="dialog.show()"
      update="dialogForm:dialogPanel"
   />
    ...

<h:form id="dialogForm">
  <p:dialog id="dialog"..... />
</h:form>

//MyBean...
public void doSomething(ActionEvent evt)
{
  //Logic
}
```

What you're missing is that you're not using the Primefaces ajax engine. There's some good tutorials at primefaces.org and the forums are very helpful. The other thing you should know is an action is probably not the best way to handle showing the dialog. There's nothing you can do with an ActionListener and it will give you a very fine level of control on the page. You can then use the action when you actually need to throw something up for navigation.

Here is a tested working example of the above (Primefaces 2.2.1)

```
//Bean
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "demoBean")
public class DemoBean
{
    private String hello = "Hello World";
    private String notSet = "not set";

    public void doAction(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        notSet = hello;
    }

    /**
     * @return the hello
     */
    public String getHello()
    {
        return hello;
    }

    /**
     * @return the notSet
     */
    public String getNotSet()
    {
        return notSet;
    }

    /**
     * @param hello
     *          the hello to set
     */
    public void setHello(String hello)
    {
        this.hello = hello;
    }

    /**
     * @param notSet
     *          the notSet to set
     */
    public void setNotSet(String notSet)
    {
        this.notSet = notSet;
    }
}
```

JSF Demo file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">


<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body class="center" style="zIndex:-3">
    <h:form id="commands">
        <p:inputText value="#{demoBean.hello}" />
        <p:commandButton 
            value="Open Dialog"
            actionListener="#{demoBean.doAction}"
            update="dialog"
            oncomplete="dialogWidget.show()"
        />
    </h:form>

    <p:dialog widgetVar="dialogWidget">
        <h:form id="dialog">
            <p:panel>
                <h3>Dialog</h3>
                <p>
                    <h:outputText value="Copied: #{demoBean.notSet}"/>
                </p>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>       
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

The thing to watch out for in Primefaces is that it is not using the built in AJAX implementation (it is compatible, but there can be "double" updates so things don't render properly). As such, when you use the widgetVar you're directly calling a show method from Javascript, you'll notice this code does the update and then calls the method.

Comment: I tested it,its not calling the popup :(

Comment: @Vikas I've updated this with a second, tested, example. I think it is pretty straightforward. Also, keep in mind "update" is part of the Primefaces API it isn't bound to <h:commandLink /> (use p:commandLink)

Comment: @Danial....Now its able to call the popup but we are not able to pass values with this link...                                      <p:commandLink id="expire" value="#{label.expire}" onclick="dlg3.show()">
                    <f:param name="certHoldertId" value="#{certHolder.accountOwner.itemIdInfo.insurerId}" />
           <f:param name="accNumberId" value="#{certHolder.accountNumberId}"/>
                 </p:commandLink>

Comment: @Vikas, I'd need to see all the code to answer in detail--but you're going to need to use an actionListener in order to "see" the values. My example pulls the data from the text box then, updates the bean via an ActionListener and then updates the dialog--it then tells the dialog to display via oncomplete="dialog.show()". I hope that helps. Keep it simple and then place with the dialog.

Comment: @Daniel....Thankyou very much.....I used the <f:setPropertyActionListener> to send the value on clicking the expire link and working fine.....

Answer (score 0):

```
    <p:commandLink id="expire" value="#{label.expire}" onclick="dlg3.show()">
                               <f:param name="certHoldertId" value="#{certHolder.accountOwner.itemIdInfo.insurerId}" />
                               <f:param name="accNumberId" value="#{certHolder.accountNumberId}"/>
                            </p:commandLink>
```

@Daniel..Its working fine with button and also able to call the popup on click of this link.But we are able to pass the values with this link. When we try to retrieve the value of certHoldertId varible with FaceContext,its give the null value.I think it return the false value.

How can we send these value with this link?

Comment: You still need to pass a value somehow through the faces context--the above code will have the parameters, but if you want to pull them down you'll need to get the information from somewhere. This either means refreshing a form containing your parameters inside the dialog--or you can use a attribute and handle it server side. I always prefer the server side solution because it is easier to debug (using an action listener). Because you're using AJAX, the URL won't be updated (making the query null on your URL). Try using an action event in this case, or RequestScoped variables.